# replacing NAs by value but excluding from geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a scatter plot and also plot a regression line for my data.

Before plotting, I want to have the NAs replaced by a fixed number to get all points in my graph and since they are all on one line, they are easily visible...

But in this way it messes up my `geom_smooth`. Is there a better solution to get the missing values replaced by a fixed number but the geom_smooth without the NAs?

```
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),
                 y=c(rnorm(40), rep(NA,60)))
df[is.na(df)] <- -5
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", fullrange=TRUE)
```

As you can see in the example, the smooth line moves to the "imputed" values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way to do it is to store your data into two different data frames :

```
df2 <- df
df2[is.na(df2)] <- -5
```

And plot them into two different layers :

```
ggplot() + geom_point(data=df2, aes(x,y)) + geom_smooth(data=df, aes(x,y), method="lm", fullrange=TRUE)
```

[image]

But maybe a cleaner way to do it would be to use `geom_rug()`, something like this :

```
dfna <- df[is.na(df$y),]
ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method="lm", fullrange=TRUE) + geom_rug(data=dfna, aes(x))
```

Which gives :

[image]

Comment: You beat me to it by about 30 seconds. This is how I would approach this as well for a reasonable sized dataframe.

Comment: Sorry ! I think the  `geom_rug()` might be better depending on the data, though.

Comment: Hah, it took me quite some minutes to define the sides correctly, since I might have missing values in x or y but want to have the rugs only on x or y... They got overplottet each time :-)